# Let $X$ and $Y$ be two uniformly distributed random variables on $[0,1]$. Find $E(X^k)$ and $E(XY^k)$.

Tags: probability, random-variables, random

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two uniformly distributed random variables on $[0,1]$. Find $E(X^k)$ and $E(XY^k)$.

How can you do this? Do you need the change of variables technique? I am a bit confused about that.

Comment: I guess you can use the definition $E(X^k)=\int_{[0,1]}x^kdx$ and $E(XY^k)=\int_{[0,1]\times[0,1]}xy^kdxdy$.

Comment: you must add an assumption: that $X,Y$ are independent.

Comment: Yes, you are right... I have overcomplicated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just expanding Alamos' comment,
$$\mathbb{E}[X^k]=\int_{0}^{1}x^k\,dx=\frac{1}{k+1},$$
and assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independent,
$$\mathbb{E}[XY^k]=\mathbb{E}[X]\cdot\mathbb{E}[Y^k]=\frac{1}{2k+2}.$$